# How do I get a count of unique nested URLs in an web application?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, burp-suite, information-gathering

I'm scoping a web application for a pentest. The  application has a number of dynamic nested URLs. I've crawled through all the URLs in the application via Burp-suite. I need to obtain a list of unique nested URLs in the application. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy links function in Burp Suite. Select the top level domain and copy links